# Clarification on template function specialization

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, function-templates

I want to create a calculator

```
template < typename T >
class Calculator
{
    public :
    Calculator ( void );
    ~Calculator ( void );

    T add(T a, T b)
    {
       return ( a + b ) ;
    }
};
```

Now I want to make this Caculator add strings, so add("Tim","Joe") shall give me "TimJoe" .

Can I use template function specialization for achieving this by making necessary changes to the existing class .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to ?

```
Calculator<std::string> a;
std::cout << a.add("Hello", " world") << std::endl;
```

This code outputs "Hello world". It's not optimal (`std::string` parameters in the `add` member function are taken by value), but it does not require a specialization to work.

**EDIT** OK, you want specialization, but you can't just specialize the `add` member function because the function is not template itself. You can either specialize the whole class :

```
template<>
class Calculator<std::string>
{
public :
    Calculator() {}
    ~Calculator() {}

    std::string add(const std::string &a, const std::string &b)
    {
        // Do std::string specific stuff
        return a + b ;
    }
};
```

Or make the `add` member function template and specialize it :

```
class Calculator
{
public :
    Calculator () {}
    ~Calculator () {}

    template<class T>
    T add(T a, T b)
    {
       return a + b;
    }
};

template<>
std::string Calculator::add<std::string>(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    // Do std::string specific stuff
    return a + b ;
}
```

With the second solution, a single `Calculator` instance will then be able to add `int`, `std::string` or whatever you need (as it's the `add` function which is template, not the `Calculator` class itself).

Comment: @silico, @icecrime, By using STL, I can do that; but I want to use template specialization

Comment: @Sujay Ghosh: Why is template specialization required? Using `std::string` is far less work than having to create a new specialization of `Calculator<T>`.

Comment: I think the second solution is a better design. If someday I want to add a custom class, and not any of the PODS, this would solve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you use `std::string`, then you won't have to deal with template specialization at all:

```
Calculator<std::string> calc;
std::string result = calc.add("Tim", "Joe");
// result contains "TimJoe"
```

This in fact does what you think it does thanks to the "magic" of the standard library, without having to write out another class.

I would, however modify your template class by making `add()` accept parameters by `const T&`:

```
template < typename T >
class Calculator
{
public :
    Calculator() {};
    ~Calculator() {};

    // Note that we're taking in parameters by const T&
    // to avoid copies if instances of T are large.
    T add(const T& a, const T& b)
    {
        return ( a + b ) ;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible (even though it's not neccessary in this case for string as already mentioned by @icecrime and @In silico)

This is the way you could specialize your member function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template < typename T >
class Calculator
{
    public :
    Calculator () {}
    ~Calculator () {}

    T add(const T& a, const T& b);
};

template <typename T>
T Calculator<T>::add(const T& a, const T& b)
{
    return (a + b);
}

template <>
string Calculator<string>::add(const string& a, const string& b)
{
    return (a + " " + b);
}

int main()
{
    Calculator<string> ccs;
    cout << ccs.add("a", "b") << endl;

    Calculator<int> cci;
    cout << cci.add(1, 2);
}
```

The output is:

```
a b
3
```

Notice, that it still behaves as you would expect, so you can not do for example this:

```
    Calculator<int> cci;
    cout << cci.add("a", "b");
```

Comment: This code does not compile .- LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: There must be something wrong on your end. It works for me without complaint with g++ -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra and it also works on codepad (which has IIRC the same flags turned on) see http://codepad.org/ZS2QJQQV